What does a graduate level course in Random Processes typically entail?
I have good familiarity with Random Processes due to the numerous Signal Processing and Communications courses I have taken, however, I will soon be taking a course solely on Random Processes. The course obviously reviews key probability theory concepts and then introduces specific Random processes without touching any Ito Calculus. I am wondering what is the purpose of such a course and what benefit can be gained from studying specific random processes in detail? Could anyone share any useful insights? Also any good resources such as textbooks and lecture series on RPs would also be welcome!

In my experience, random processes served as the foundational math to understand the derivations of many different statistical signal processing techniques, e.g. Kalman Filters, Hidden Markov Models, Detection and Estimation, Linear Prediction, Adaptive Filters, Spectral Estimation, etc. Many of those things can be used without knowledge of the underlying mathematical derivation, but to understand where and when to apply them it is helpful to have gone through the derivations, for which random processes is key.

"The course obviously reviews key probability theory concepts and then introduces specific Random processes without touching any Ito Calculus" As someone who did the exercises for the basic stochastics courses for EEs, which entailed basics of stochastic processes, I'm very unclear how describing stochastic processes would work without calculus. I honestly don't see any way you could quantify anything if you're not dealing with join probability functions, derivatives and integrals. So, I'd ask the lecturer whether they have a syllabus for their course, and judge by that, instead of asking …

… people on the internet which cannot know what that specific course would do. That course must be very different to what I taught on correlation, ergodicity, Markov properties, memory, walks, arrival processes, … none of which is even definable without getting into a fair bit of calculus. And frankly, I consider the content of what we did as relatively "usual" for students who later on go into signal processing and communications engineering. Really, you seem to be asking the wrong people here! Explaining their course is a lecturer's job, so drop them an email – they usually like that.

@MarcusMüller I think OP was referring to Itô calculus: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/It%C3%B4_calculus Also, completely agree with the drop your professor an email advice. Works wonders from time to time...

@AhsanYousaf please note the loud sound you just heard outside. That's my hand hitting my forehead. My brain was correcting "Ito" into "into", and that the prof didn't want to start into calculus at all  … this makes more sense; if you don't do (much) stoch diff equations, or quantum mechanics, you can live without. Sorry about the noise (ha, a pun!)
